# request.getInputStream does not show the real string content

Tags: java, post, request

I'm having a `POST` request that is like the one below:

```
<form action="get_eD_XML" method="POST">
<input type='text' name='data'value='<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:epsos="urn:epsos-org:ep:medication" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">...</ClinicalDocument>' />
<input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to get the value using:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject();
    String inputLine;
    String data = "";
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

        data =inputLine.replace("data=", "");
    }

    System.out.println(data);
}
```

However, the content of data is something like:

```
%3CClinicalDocument+xmlns%3D%22urn%3Ahl7-org%3Av3%22+xmlns%3Aepsos%3D%22urn%3Aepsos-org%3Aep%3Amedication%22+xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22%3E%
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What stack are you using? Can you show us the whole method?

Comment: @Rashin I've updated my question to include it.

Comment: What is returned by `request.getParameterValues()`?

Comment: Using `System.out.println(request.getParameterValues(data));` I get `null`.

Comment: Try with `request.getParameterNames()`. This should return the parameters that are passed to this request (should contains 'data'). If it contains 'data' then try `System.out.println(request.getParameterValues("data"))`.

Comment: @Rashin That's it. Thank you! Put is as an answer to accept it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the parameters passed to this request by using `request.getParameterNames()`.
This should contains the value 'data'.
Calling `request.getParameterValues("data")` you can get the decoded value for this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using apache.commons.io?

```
public String convert(InputStream inputStream, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    return IOUtils.toString(inputStream, charset);
}
```

here's the POM entry

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```